# Sufficient time to fill the bucket

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Suppose that we have a pierced bucket, and that the hole empties the bucket in four hours. We place the bucket under two faucets at the same time. If the bucket weren’t pierced, the first faucet would fill it in three hours and the second would fill it in six hours. How long will it take to fill the initially empty pierced bucket using both faucets?

Comment: No problem! I’m afraid this is more of a maths textbook problem than a maths puzzle though, and the site consensus has ruled that those are off topic here. (I liked this one nevertheless, so I tried to solve it too.)

Comment: Thank you another time, I am new here ans i dont understand why they are down voting my question ?

Comment: It’s probably because of [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2783/are-math-textbook-style-problems-on-topic).

Comment: I don't think this is a math problem. All the answers below are wrong. My answer would be that maybe the bucket never fills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flow in is $\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2}$ buckets per hour, and assuming that the flow out is not dependent on the water level, it’s a constant $\frac{1}{4}$ buckets per hour.

Subtracting the latter from the former, the bucket fills at the rate of $\frac{1}{4}$ buckets per hour, so it takes four hours to fill the bucket.

Comment: Agreed, and stated much more succinctly than my answer.

Comment: This is definitely wrong, though it is marked as correct. A bucket will drain at a rate that increases rapidly as the height of the water in the bucket increases.

Answer (score 2):

The bucket will fill in

> 4 hours

Rationale:

> The bucket empties at a rate of x/4 gallons per hour (where x = the size of the bucket in gallons).  The faucets fill the bucket at a rate of x/3 plus x/6 gallons per hour or a total fill rate of x/2 gal/hr.

Therefore:

> The net fill rate is x/2 - x/4 = x/4 gal/hr.  It will fill up x gallons in 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

It would take 4 hours to fill it.
First faucet will fill one third of the bucket in one hour.
Second faucet will fill one sixth of the bucket in one hour.
The hole empties one fourth of the bucket in one hour.
$\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$ of bucket will be filled in one hour.  Thus the bucket will be full in $4$ hours